# GLB Texture Broken in WebXR Vision Pro

Tags: webxr, vision-pro

When glb object is loading in Web Browser in Vision Pro, it works beautifully when glb doesn't have textures in it. However with env textures it breaks in a weird way. Anyone can guess what could have caused this problem? (I also inquired Apple for this too)

Open a web browser in Vision Pro Simulator.

Type this address.

https://3d.camilleworld.com/e/?idx=152

Then the world texture is broken as follows.
[image]